# How to assign select into variable and use it in case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have query in postgres:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (Select money from Bank)  is not null THEN (Select money from Bank) ELSE -1 end;
```

Is there any possibilities not repeat this subquery in 'THEN' ?
I would like to do something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ((Select money from Bank) = MONEY)  is not null THEN MONEY ELSE -1 end;
```

I need to do this in one Select statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE( (Select money from Bank), -1)
```

The subquery might still be run twice (due to the semantics of `COALESCE()`) -- I'm not sure how Postgres optimizes this.

You can fix this by moving the logic to the `from` clause:

```
select coalesce(b.money, -1)
from (Select money from Bank) b
```

Note:  This will not return any rows if `Bank` is empty.  My guess, though, is that you have simplified the query and there are more conditions.  If `bank` really has at most one row, then you can just use:

```
select coalesce(max(b.money), -1)
from bank b
```

If this is really a more complicated query, you might need a lateral join:

```
select . . ., coalesce(b.money, -1)
from . . . left join lateral
     (Select money from Bank) b;
```

Comment: First example and second aren't equivalent if the subquery returns no results; first version will return 1 row with -1 and second will return 0 rows.